# Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed error

Tags: vb.net

I am using VS2012's register control. I added a custom code after the sign up is finalized (the continue button) which leads to a second form where other information is filled. Every time I create an account it throws the following exception: Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed. Honestly this is the first time I've seen this error. The account is properly created, but I can't have it blowing up every time someone wants to continue with the sign up. Any help would be appreciated!

Stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.]
 aSuite.SiteMaster.master_Page_PreLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\aSuite\aSuite\Site.Master.vb:40
  System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreLoad(EventArgs e) +121
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +699
```

Comment: Bumping just in case anyone has an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the view state on your page is set to be true or even remove it as the default is true. This error may occur if EnableViewState was set to be false in your page declaration.

```
EnableViewState="true"
```