# validation of anti-xsrf token failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I created a new asp.net web forms(with master pages) application for a very simple submission form. I used visual studio 2012 to create the web project and it added the code for preventing cross site script forgery on the site.master.cs.

However upon testing , if a user signs and is inactive for a few minutes, and then clicks logout button,we are getting this error (on the site.master.cs)

```
Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.

       Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.

Source Error: 
Line 61:                     || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] !=    

  (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))

 Line 62:                 {

 Line 63:                     throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");


   Line 64:                 }

 Line 65:             }
```

What can we do to avoid this?

Comment: That isn't particularly secure.  You should use ASP.Net's built-in CSRF protection.

Comment: Yes, i m not saying, remove this, but how to prevent this error from showing up

Comment: You can find a solution for this here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330159/validation-of-anti-xsrf-token-failed-error?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330159/validation-of-anti-xsrf-token-failed-error?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Thats entirely up to you. Handle the error as you like..
Its probable in your case you restarted the web server and your viewstate died or did this not knowingly.

Are you using Owin? if you are using Owin there is a bug that messes up Session and Viewstate. Before you authenticate a user create a Session variable (anything) e.g Session["Blah"] = test.

Just add in code to handle the error (Redirect the user to another page).

Comment: I know this is old, but can you expand on why this is a bug, where it is, how to correct it (setting a session variable does not work at all - in the master page nor any web form)? This problem is a nightmare and we've only been able to solve it by disabling the feature (just too buggy for a real website).